# Error when Overriding Django ModelForm field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am having trouble when I try to override a Django ModelForm fields.

My models.py is like this:

```
from django.db import models

class CadastroParticipantes(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    num_cartas_solicitadas = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

And my forms.py is like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import *

class FormCadastroParticipante(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CadastroParticipantes
        fields = ('nome', 'sobrenome', 'cpf', 'email')
        exclude=('num_cartas_solicitadas')
        widgets = { 'nome' : attrs={'title': 'Seu primeiro nome.'}}
```

When I run the server and try to access I get this message:

**

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (forms.py, line 9)
```

**

can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance to all! (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to specify a widget class. It should be something like this:

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput

class FormCadastroParticipante(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CadastroParticipantes
        fields = ('nome', 'sobrenome', 'cpf', 'email')
        exclude=('num_cartas_solicitadas', )
        widgets = { 'nome' : TextInput(attrs={'title': 'Seu primeiro nome.'}), }
```

Change `TextInput` to your desired widget class. Please also note that `exclude` attribute in `Meta` class accept a list, don't forget a trailing comma if there is only one list member.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you define `attrs={'title': 'Seu primeiro nome.'}` outside class Meta and then you can say `widgets = { 'nome' : attrs}`